# Connection between quasifibrations and homotopy cartesian squares

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let me first fix the definitions.

A map $p\colon E\rightarrow B$ is called a quasi-fibration, iff the canonical inclusion $p^{-1}(b)\rightarrow hofib_b(p)$ is a weak equivalence for all for all $b\in B$.

Consider a commutative square
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
Y & \to & E
\cr\downarrow&&\downarrow
\cr
X& \to &B
\end{array}.
$$ Replace $E\rightarrow B$ by a fibration $E'\rightarrow B$ via the usual construction and pull back the fibration to a fibration over $X$. We then obtain a canonical map from $Y$ to the pullback. I call the diagram homotopy cartesian iff this map is a weak equivalence.

Obviously a map $p\colon E\rightarrow B$ is a quasi-fibration, iff the square
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}
p^{-1}(\{b\}) & \to & E
\cr\downarrow&&\downarrow
\cr
\{b\}& \to &B
\end{array}
$$ is homotopy cartesian for all $b\in B$.

Can one characterize homotopy cartesian squares in terms of quasi-fibrations to obtain a statement of the shape "The square is cartesian iff a map constructed out of the square is a quasifibration"?

Comment: Are you looking for something like this fibre-wise characterization: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/homotopy+pullback#HomotopyFiberCharacterization?

Comment: No, I'm aware of the fiberwise characterization. I'd rather would like to have a statement of the shape I proposed.